# How to recover deleted .ssh/known_host entry?

Tags: server, 18.04, permissions, ssh, openssh

I created a droplet (basically a server) to host a website on DigitalOcean. I connected to it using openssh on my computer, and it was working fine. Then I decided to delete the 3rd out of 3 entries inside of the ~/.ssh/known_hosts file (I'm, not sure why I did this).

Now when I try to connect to the droplet using `ssh username@ipaddress` it returns an error: `username@ipaddress Permission denied (publickey)`. Is there a way to obtain the history of the known_hosts file? Maybe I need to copy-paste my public key somewhere?

**Conclusion**: delete server and start all over

Answer (score 4):

> Now when I try to connect to the droplet using ssh username@ipaddress it returns an error: username@ipaddress Permission denied (publickey). Is there a way to obtain the history of the known_hosts file? Maybe I need to copy-paste my public key somewhere?

`known_hosts` keep a history of the public *server* keys your client has seen. It is used to protect against a man in the middle-attack, as that would lead to a changed remote public key.

It is thus used to authenticate the server to the client, not the opposite way. If you connect to an unknown host, you will be prompted if you want to trust the key or not.

You deleting lines in `known_hosts` is not the reason why you get permission denied when you try to connect using a keypair. Run `ssh -vvv user@host` to get more information about why you get connection denied.

Comment: You might be correct, but I assumed since it happened after the case that it was the problem.

It attempts 'trying private key' 3 times but fails because of 'No such file or directory'. From what I know about keys, it should try id_rsa against the id_rsa.public on the server, but it doesn't. Any ideas?

Comment: The key should be added to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server.

Comment: The key is in there, yes. But the ssh -vvv makes it look like the private key version of the authorized key in the server wasn't used in 'Trying private key'.